# Set content of vue 3 single file components' style tag

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I need to present some random/dynamic html data in my project that might contain style tags, by default vue.js doesn't allow style tags in the template to avoid messing styles that is a very good option.
To make my project work I tried some runtime-component projects on github but they doesn't accept css styles in the way I need, so I came up with the solution of creating my own runtime component with accepting css styles data.
What I want in code is sth like:

```js
<template>
  <div v-html="template"></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "DynamicTemplate",
  props: {template: String, style: String}
}
</script>

<style scoped>
// style data goes here
</style>
```

Any alternative working solution is welcome too :)

I tried `v-html` and `v-text` attributes on the component style tag (without any results) and also using css `@import` statement with base64 encoded css codes (got some errors like Cannot read properties of undefined), but none of them worked :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can encapsulate the data inside the style tags inside the component tag provided by vue in this manner ->

```
  <component :is="'style'"> .test-class { color: red; }....Your style data </component>
```

An example of the same can be found in this project I created

https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-dewdney-id9erd?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

Edit 1 =>
After reading the comment as I think the CSS scope compilation is done during the build process not during runtime thus having css at runtime won't scope it an alternate solution for this can be embedding your HTML code inside an iframe and passing your code to the iframe using the srcdoc attribute.An example of the same is given below

https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-cherry-zzv3wk?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

```
<template>
  <iframe style="width: 100vw; height: 80vh" :srcdoc="htmlCssCode"></iframe>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      htmlCssCode: `Your Html code here`

<html>
```

Comment: As I said before, I'm not writing neither input html codes nor style codes, so if there be any selector like `div { color: red; }` will affect every div in the window, I need sth more scoped, but to complete your idea, if there be any way to compile scss in such style elements, I can add a unique id to parent div and use it like `#parent-id { {{styleData}} }` and compile it to css, just like how vue itself adds a unique preset to each selector. I've done some researches and tests but I couldn't find a way to compile scss to css in browser

Comment: Please check my answer again have updated it

Comment: I'd already thought about using iframes but I was looking for another working solution, btw seems iframe is the best option for now and your answer works, thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of passing that can pass dynamic HTML data in your project with an example using style tags

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-html="template" :style="style"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'DynamicTemplate',
  props: {
    template: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    style: {
      type: Object,
      required: false,
      default: () => {}
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Here is the component being used.

```
<DynamicTemplate
  :template="<p>This is some dynamic HTML content</p>"
  :style="{ color: 'red', font-size: '14px' }">
</DynamicTemplate>
```

Comment: the styles are not inline, styles are full css for selectors like `div.class-name {color: 'red';}` and so on

Comment: In line-css was an example, passing classes is a different use case. You can do the same thing by accepting classes instead of styles by using :class instead of :style

I posted another solution above specifically to accept classes. I hope this helps

Otherwise you have to pass raw HTML if you want to work around the limitations of Vue.js when comes to passing dynamically daya

You can also dynamically change data similiar to react.js. It works well too

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of passing that can pass dynamic HTML data in your project with an example of passing classes dynamically

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-html="template" :class="classes"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'DynamicTemplate',
  props: {
    template: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    classes: {
      type: Object,
      required: false,
      default: () => {}
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Here is the component being used.

```
<DynamicTemplate
  :template="template"
  :classes="classes"
/>
```